# How can I change Checkbox color when I click and unclick?

Tags: android, android-checkbox

When I click on checkbox color change of that checkbox and rest of check box remain another color so how can I change the color of checkbox ?

```java
if (CountryList.get(pos).getSelected()) {
    CountryList.get(pos).setSelected(false);
    holder.country.setBackgroundResource(R.color.btnbckgrd);
} else {
    CountryList.get(pos).setSelected(true);
    holder.country.setBackgroundResource(R.color.lightgreen);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try this:
mSelectedItem = -1;
holder.country.setBackgroundResource(mSelectedItem == position ? 
R.color.lightgreen: R.color.btnbckgrd);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use style for this

```
<style name="yourStyle" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">your_color</item> <!-- for uncheck state -->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">your color</item> <!-- for check state -->
</style>
```

set it in xml like this

```
<CheckBox
     android:theme="@style/yourStyle"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `android:tint="@color/your_color"` in your layout file??

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer which is working on all API would be:

Create style:

```
<style name="CheckBox">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/light_grey</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/ts_white</item>
    </style>
```

and use it like this:

```
   <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
                  .....
                    android:theme="@style/Bonus.CheckBox"
                  ..... />
```

after setting style you wont going to need to check views background programmaticaly

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  final CheckBox cbox= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb_flash);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Set the Flash CheckBox Text Color
            cbox.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

            // Set the Flash CheckBox Background Color
            cbox.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#cbff75"));
        }
    });

 if(checkbox.isChecked()){
   cbox.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

            // Set the Flash CheckBox Background Color
            cbox.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#cbff75"));

  }else{
 //chenge color
   }
```

> [refer this link another method](https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/08/android-checkbox-color.html)